# iOS/Safari cutting trailing zero BEFORE decimal point

Tags: php, ios, woocommerce

This one is mind boggling. I have tried several ways to keep the `0` before the decimal point, however only in Safari/iOS is this being cut, making it difficult to determine.

I am trying to display the max price of a variation product on the archive page. This (as well as several other approaches, note - the commented out `number_format` approach) works perfectly fine on Windows or Android, using Firefox, Chrome and IE.

However, on iOS / Safari, numbers such as `150` are coming back as `15`. The last 0 is also being trimmed, despite it being BEFORE the decimal point.

The `var_dump()` are both returning strings. The raw returns `150.00` as expected, while the `$price` variable is returning `150`, as desired... on desktop and Android only.

```
$raw_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true );
//$price = number_format($raw_price, 0, '.', ' ');
$price = preg_replace( '/' . preg_quote( wc_get_price_decimal_separator(), '/' ) .  '0++$/', '', $raw_price );

    echo '<div class="corner">$' . $price . '</div>';
    var_dump($price);
    var_dump($raw_price);
```

I should mention that I am using the built in filter to trim zeros site-wide, used below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', '__return_true' );
```

Which may potentially be affecting things? I can't see why, however I can't find a solution to this one.

Comment: The PHP isn't executed by the browser so I'd look at client side things. Maybe you have some JS targeting IOS/Safari, or maybe Safari is trying to turn your prices into phone numbers or something stupid.